# Postman mockserver Adding Examples

Tags: postman, mockserver

Imagine a scenario where i have a "sales" endpoint. It can be further filtered on say by region i.e europe and america

Steps i followed

1. I created mock server and created sales/{{customregion}} like shown below

[image: createms]

2)named the mockser testms

3)now i click on the request and then click on **Examples** on top right .
I rename default to **europe** and add another eg as **america**

[image]

4. same way i created random json response sample for  **america** as well

[image]

5. Now my **question is below**
   If i **mistype** the endpoint i still get the result. Let's look at each case

Eg1)https://21ad39c9-aebc-49a5-88d0-8e1abad0a2d8.mock.pstmn.io/sales/europe
result as expected gives data configured for europe
Same works for america as well i.e it gives results configured for america

Eg2)instead of **europe** i give **europes** and it still works ..how ??eg below

[image]

Eg3) Same way i gave **eurospe** instead of **europe** and that worked too.

Eg4) only if i mistype it completely it gives below error which is correct

[image]

**whole thing has got me a little confused**. First how does {{customregion}} variable works and how it works even if there is a typo. But if misspelled, may be more than 1 character it gives an error. Can anyone please explain this in detail

Comment: what was your example

Comment: Also your headers, Are you using matching response header ?

Comment: no am not using any response header

Comment: @PDHide... i have attached screenshots what i did

Comment: In your screenshot example part is missing

Comment: In the first screenshot only till status code is there example is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a mispelled route Postman tries to return the "closest" matching example route as a fallback. It is not possible to predict this deterministically.